# Камера от третьего лица на Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Всем привет. 
Изучаю на досуге новую для себя тему - three.js не не обессудьте за глупый вопрос :)

Вообщем, я реализовал движения обьекта, а также вращение камеры вокруг него как в играх от 3го лица, но я хотел бы сделать, чтоб при движении камеры из стороны в сторону, обьект также поворачивался в ту же сторону, например я веду мышку вправо и обьект тоже поворачивается вправо. Не уверен, что смогу выложить куда-то, чтоб показать демку поэтому вот ссылка на gitlab:

https://gitlab.com/k0mar/drizzle

Установка в три шага:

```
npm i
npm run prod
node server.js
```

Логика камеры тута:

```
class ThirdPersonCamera extends Camera {
    boot(domElement) {
        this.cameraManager = new CameraManager(domElement);
    }

    tick(target = null) {
        if (target !== null) {
            this.cameraManager.target.applyMatrix4(target.matrixWorld);
            this.cameraManager.target.set(target.position.x, target.position.y + 2, target.position.z);
        }

        let targetX = this.cameraManager.target.x;
        let targetY = this.cameraManager.target.y;
        let targetZ = this.cameraManager.target.z;

        let radius = this.cameraManager.radius;
        let theta = this.cameraManager.theta;
        let phi = this.cameraManager.phi;

        let posX = targetX + radius * Math.sin(theta * Math.PI / 360) * Math.cos(phi * Math.PI / 360);
        let posY = targetY + radius * Math.sin(phi * Math.PI / 360);
        let posZ = targetZ + radius * Math.cos(theta * Math.PI / 360) * Math.cos(phi * Math.PI / 360);


        this.position.set(posX, posY, posZ);
        this.lookAt(this.cameraManager.target);
    }
}
```

А это CameraManager:

```
class CameraManager extends Manager {
    implements() {
        this.sensitivity = new Vector2(1, 1);
        this.target = new Vector3();
        this.character = {};

        this.radius = 15;
        this.theta = 0;
        this.phi = 0;
    }

    realised(deltaX, deltaY) {
        this.theta -= deltaX * this.sensitivity.x;
        this.theta %= 720;

        this.phi += deltaY * this.sensitivity.y;
        this.phi = Math.min(170, Math.max(-170, this.phi));
    }

    event() {
        this.boundLockedPointer = () => this.domElement.requestPointerLock();
        this.boundMouseMove = event => this.realised(event.movementX, event.movementY);

        this.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', this.boundLockedPointer, false);
        this.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', this.boundMouseMove, false);
    }
}
```

Метод **tick** в ThirdPersonCamera вызывает какждый фрейм, а *target* который в него приходит, это сам персонаж.

Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем все оказалось проще чем я думал)) Нужно было крутить обьект по кватернионам камеры:

```
let quaternion = new Quaternion(target.quaternion.x, this.quaternion.y, target.quaternion.z, this.quaternion.w);

target.setRotationFromQuaternion(quaternion);
target.quaternion.normalize();
target.rotateY(Math.PI); //Поворачиваем обьект на 180 градусов
```